# Need to increment by 1 every time key is pressed-JavaFx

Tags: java, javafx, draw, increment

Every time I press a key, Right in this case, I need my p1Start value, in this case the p1StartX to increment by 1. This is used to "Draw" a path in a 2D array of type rectangle.

My problem is, it only increments once. How can I fix this?

```
 scene2.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
        int p1StartX = 5;
        int p1StartY = 25;
        int p2StartX = 60;
        int p2StartY = 25;

        if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.LEFT) {
            p1.setDirection(1);
            p1.update();
        } else if (e.getCode() == KeyCode.RIGHT) {
            p1StartX++;
            gameGrid[p1StartY][p1StartX].setFill(p1.getPlayerClr());

            System.out.println("Player 1: Right");

        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because `p1StartX` is defined inside the scope of your listener.

Move it to a class member (static or not - up to your design...) - and things will be O.K.

Moreover, I'm pretty sure this goes for all of your defined `int` values.

Like so:

```
//some class definition...
private int p1StartX;

//Use a constructor to init the value of p1StartX.

...

scene2.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {

    ....

        p1StartX++;

    }
```

Comment: Thank you, I used my other class to create a incrementor everytime it was pressed and it worked, I will love you forever!